# Cocos2d background sound not playing a second time C++/Win10 UWP

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x, windows-10

I'm using cocoss2d with c++ on windows 10 and I'm trying to play background music. It works the first time I debug the game but on the second time I hit run it throws these exceptions

```
Exception thrown at 0x765F3E28 (KernelBase.dll) in MiniGolf.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.
Exception thrown at 0x765F3E28 (KernelBase.dll) in MiniGolf.exe: 0x0000000E: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
Assert failed: getFileSize should be override by platform FileUtils
Assertion failed!
```

I simply use this line to start the music.

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playBackgroundMusic("level_music1.wav",true);
```

I'm not sure what's going on can anyone share a light with me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cocos2d-x 3.9
CCWinRTUtils.cpp
line 336 added

```
if (ret[0] == '/') {
    ret = ret.substr(1, ret.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to rebuild the project after adding this line to CCWinRTUtils.cpp?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! It's not that good fix, but still.

File: CCWinRTUtils.cpp
Method: createMappedCacheFile

I have commented if/else construction and call `FileUtils::getInstance()->removeFile(prevFile)` all the time.

Now it works fine on both Windows10 and Windows Phone 8.1.

As I understand now the caching works only for current session. The previous solution (caching by hashtag) was for caching sounds loaded from the Internet and not needed for local files.